# LEGO 75192 UCS Millennium Falcon: I need to store this set, not display it

Tags: star-wars, storage

I need to store, for moving purposes, my [75192 LEGO UCS Millennium Falcon](https://brickset.com/sets/75192-1/Millennium-Falcon). All I see are display cases for sale.  Does anyone know of a storage bin or shipping container that can hold this ship?  I do not want to take it apart.

Comment: Is partly disassembling not an option? Usually, you can remove large sections, put them in separate bags and put all those bags into a packing case with additional upholstery. In this case, you might even use the original LEGO box. I can store it for you, if you want :)

Comment: I recommend one of those boxes that people smuggle stuff in.

Answer (score 2):

First, movers are widely varying in quality.  You might get folks that are poets and scholars or you might get somebody that drops every box.  If you've gone with the cheapest movers or this is your first move, it is probably best to assume the worst.  To me this means it is comparable to shipping something through the Post Office.

Given the size of this set it is going to be difficult to get a box that is big enough for it to fit flat.  I would plan on building a plywood box the right size.  If you go with cardboard boxes, get two of different sizes so they can be nested.  Cardboard boxes of adequate width will probably be really tall.  You should cut the vertical corners of the box to make it shorter when the top flaps are folded together.

Then you need to find a material to go between the box and the model.  If you can get foam and cut it to shape that will be easier to deal with, but you could use bubble wrap or packing peanuts.  There's glue for bonding the foam to itself.  I've also used various sizes of towels for packing material around LEGO models.

Particularly if you use packing peanuts, make sure to bag the model before putting it in.  Things that stick out like the radome could get lost, so bag them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I had hopes that there was something pre made but that now is sounding doubtful.

Thanks

—Rocco—

Answer (score 0):

I am basing this answers on your [comment](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15110/lego-75192-ucs-millennium-falcon-i-need-to-store-this-set-not-display-it#comment18495_15115) wanting something "pre made", which I take to mean you can buy it from a store.

Depending on what you budget is you could a try [Pelican™](https://www.pelican.com/us/en/) case or a similar product. Any brand that comes with a hard exterior box and foam padding should suffice. The foam can be shaped to what your requirements are.

I suggest Pelican because I use them to ship sensors and calibrated equipment through a ground shipper (e.g. FedEx, UPS) for work. So you won't have to worry about the moving crew damaging the set.

With the [dimensions of the set](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/millennium-falcon-75192) being "over 8” (21cm) high, 33” (84cm) long and 22” (56cm) wide"; the case you would need to go with [1730 Protector Transport Case.](https://www.pelican.com/us/en/product/cases/transport-case/protector/1730)